# React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, jsdom, reactjs-testutils

I'm trying to simulate a scroll event with ReactJS and JSDOM.

Initially I tried the following:

```
var footer = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(Component, 'footer');
footer.scrollTop = 500;
TestUtils.Simulate.scroll(footer.getDOMNode());
//I tried this as well, but no luck
//TestUtils.Simulate.scroll(footer);
```

The scroll event is not propagated at all. Then, I've manually created the event and everything worked fine:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("scroll", false, true);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

**Question**: Am I doing something wrong with the TestUtils? How can I make that to work?

Answer (score 10):

My situation may be different than the OP's, but I was struggling with the a similar problem and found my way here after lots and lots of searching.  I realized the crux of my problem was that `TestUtils.Simulate.scroll()` only simulates a scroll event dispatched by a specific React component (e.g. when you have `overflow: scroll` set on that component) and not a scroll event dispatched by `window`.

In particular, I was trying to test a scroll handler I'd set up in a React class like this:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
},

componentWillUnmount: function () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
},
```

To test `onScroll()`, I finally figured out that I had to simulate dispatching a scroll event from `window`, like this:

```
document.body.scrollTop = 100;
window.dispatchEvent(new window.UIEvent('scroll', { detail: 0 }));
```

That worked great for me.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717499/testing-for-mouse-wheel-events) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel), I believe TestUtils simulates the scrolling via a `WheelEvent`, which means it needs a `deltaY` parameter to know how far to scroll. That would look like this:

```
TestUtils.Simulate.scroll(footer.getDOMNode(), { deltaY: 500 });
```

Comment: Actually this was a false alarm. It did not work. The event did not get propagated.